# Find text in a file and copy it to another file

Tags: text-processing, files, grep, search

Is there any command in Linux to find text in a file and if found then copy it in another file?

Using `sed -i` we can find text but how to copy whole line in another file?

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `sed -i` - it would overwrite your original file.

Use grep instead.

```
grep "text to find" input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the question, the op wants to find the text and put it in another file, not the whole line which the text was found.

I would use the `grep -o 'pattern' input_file > output_file`.

The `-o` flag:

```
-o, --only-matching
       Print  only  the  matched  (non-empty) parts of a matching line, 
       with each such part on a separateoutput line.
```

---

Example:

```
$ cat tmp
01/21/21 - foo
01/22/21 - bar
01/23/21 - foo
01/24/21 - bar

$ grep -o 'foo' tmp > foo

$ cat foo
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed` outputs to `stdout` by default. To output to a file, redirect `sed`'s `stdout` to a file using the `>` operator (if you want to create a new file) or using the `>>` operator (if you want to append the output to an already existing file):

```
sed '/text/' inputfile > outputfile
sed '/text/' inputfile >> outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep. Lets say you want search in the file source_file , and the second file where you have the lines that you want to search from is input_file. 
Use

```
    grep -f input_file source_file > output_file
```

Let's say your source_file is

```
    Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall
    Humpty Dumpty had a great fall
    All the King's horses and 
    All the Queen's men
    COuld not put Humpty together again
```

And input file is

```
    Humpty
    Queen
```

The your output fie would be

```
    Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall
    Humpty Dumpty had a great fall
    All the Queen's men
    COuld not put Humpty together again
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i` is for inplace editing:

from `man sed`

```
-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
      edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)
```

---

`sed` is a good choice, but you could also use `awk`

```
 awk '/<your_pattern>/' foo > bar
```

---

*Example*

```
$ cat foo
foo bar foobar
bar foo bar
bar foo

$ awk '/foobar/' foo > bar

$ cat bar
foo bar foobar
```