# find rows matching with another file and store them in a separate file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have population file looks like this

```
pop.file
HG1W
HG2W
HG3W
HG4W
...
```

and another file contains individual IDs (there are 2 rows per individual, R1, and R2).

```
ind.file
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_HG1W26-7_353_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_HG1W26-7_353_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_14.ED14_HG1W35-2_310_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_14.ED14_HG1W35-2_310_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_HG2W9-3_342_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_HG2W9-3_342_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_1.ED1_HG2W12-3_33_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_1.ED1_HG2W12-3_33_R2.fastq.gz
...
```

I want to store individuals from each population in a separate file and get output file like this

```
head HG1.population
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_HG1W26-7_353_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_HG1W26-7_353_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_14.ED14_HG1W35-2_310_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_14.ED14_HG1W35-2_310_R2.fastq.gz


head HG2.population
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_HG2W9-3_342_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_HG2W9-3_342_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_1.ED1_HG2W12-3_33_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_1.ED1_HG2W12-3_33_R2.fastq.gz
```

Comment: can you crosscheck your desired output?

Comment: Related grep - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287389/how-to-find-words-from-one-file-in-another-file and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210453/find-text-in-a-file-and-copy-it-to-another-file

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F_ '
  NR==FNR {ind[substr($1,1,3)]++} 
  {i = substr($3,1,3); f = i ".population"} 
  i in ind {print >> f; close(f)}
' pop.file ind.file
```

then

```
$ head HG*
==> HG1.population <==
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_HG1W26-7_353_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_18.ED17_HG1W26-7_353_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_14.ED14_HG1W35-2_310_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_14.ED14_HG1W35-2_310_R2.fastq.gz

==> HG2.population <==
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_HG2W9-3_342_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2622.001.Index_16.ED16_HG2W9-3_342_R2.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_1.ED1_HG2W12-3_33_R1.fastq.gz
HI.2613.007.Index_1.ED1_HG2W12-3_33_R2.fastq.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for i in `cat pop.file | cut -c -3`
do
    grep $i ind.file > $i.population
done
```